# Ecological regime shifts and natural resource variability

Tags: resources

I am thinking of the interaction of two different uncertainties; ecological regime shift uncertainty and natural resource variability.

For example, for fishes, we know that the fish stock is exposed to an abrupt decrease in risk (regime shift). Also, there is always natural resource variability, which represents another source of uncertainty.

Are there any scientific evidence that natural resource variability increases/decreases after the occurrence of a regime shift?

I gave an example for fishes but it can be any sort of common pool resources.

Comment: i think this question might be a better fit over at https://biology.stackexchange.com/ if you want your question migrated you can ping one of our moderators.